# Laravel mail pretend prints nothing

Tags: php, email, laravel

I set `'pretend' => true,` in the `mail.php`, created this `new.php` view:

```
<body>
    <div>
        E-mail: {{ $user->email }}<br>
        User: {{ $user->username }}<br>
        Pass: {{ $user->password }}<br>
    </div>
</body>
```

Then in my controller I use this code to "send" the mail:

```
$data['user'] = $user;
Mail::send('emails.new', $data, function($message) use ($user)
{
    $message->to('example@example.hu', $user->username)->subject('Account');
});
```

The output in the log file is only this:

> [2013-08-30 11:27:56] log.INFO: Pretending to mail message to: example@example.com [] []

I tried with a full HTML view, also with another view that contains only strings, no variables, but the output is the same.

Is this the way how this should work? Shouldn't it print the whole message, title, etc? Is there a problem with the code or this is the proper output?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you set `'pretend' => true` in `app/config/mail.php` then no mail is ever sent, you get just a message in the log, like this:

```
[2014-07-17 14:15:07] production.INFO:
    Pretending to mail message to: foo@example.com [] []
```

---

However, if you leave `'pretend' => false` and instead use the `log` driver (`'driver' => 'log'`, available since Laravel 4.2), then instead of sending the mail, you'll get the whole mail content written into the log:

```
[2014-07-17 14:15:14] production.DEBUG:
    Message-ID: <da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890@example.com>

Date: Thu, 17 Jul 2014 14:15:15 +0000

Subject: Welcome!
From: Ahmad <ahmad@example.com>
To: John Smith <foo@example.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable


    Order confirmed!

 [] []
```

Comment: I made this entry in `config/local/mail.php` and left `pretend => false`. I find seeing the actual output to be more useful.

Comment: This is an excellent answer - should be in the annotations in `config/mail.php`

Comment: note that the log driver is supported as of laravel 4.2

Comment: Note that this is now outdated and the `pretend` functionality has been removed

Answer (score 10):

If you actually want to view the contents of the message (for instance when testing user account verification or password reset emails) in the /storage/logs logfile; You can modify your local copy of vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php and in the logMessages function modify it to look like

```
protected function logMessage($message)
{
    $emails = implode(', ', array_keys((array) $message->getTo()));
    $body = $message->getBody();
    $this->logger->info("Pretending to mail message to: {$emails} :-: {$body}");
}
```

Then you will see the body of the message in the logs.

Comment: You can get email subject by adding $subject = $message->getSubject();

Comment: no, dont do this, this is changing the core, the asnwer below (@virtilink) is the correct one

Comment: Just to update the answer, I recommend you don't do any of these things. Instead run a local SMTP server built specifically for local development purposes: http://mailcatcher.me/

Answer (score 8):

This is the normal behaviour of pretend in the Laravel Mailer system. It will not render your message anywhere, not even in the log, it will just log that a mail message was pretended to be sent. Look at the related source code:

```
/**
 * Send a Swift Message instance.
 *
 * @param  Swift_Message  $message
 * @return void
 */
protected function sendSwiftMessage($message)
{
    if ( ! $this->pretending)
    {
        return $this->swift->send($message);
    }
    elseif (isset($this->logger))
    {
        $this->logMessage($message);
    }
}

/**
 * Log that a message was sent.
 *
 * @param  Swift_Message  $message
 * @return void
 */
protected function logMessage($message)
{
    $emails = implode(', ', array_keys($message->getTo()));

    $this->logger->info("Pretending to mail message to: {$emails}");
}
```

Comment: Link to the code: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php

Answer (score 8):

I include this in my send callbacks:

```
Mail::send(array('emails.html','emails.text'),$data,function($message) use($data)
{
   //Set $message data
   if(Config::get('mail.pretend')) Log::info(View::make('emails.html',$data)->render());
}
```

Alternately, you can pass the views render into another view to see the html rendered in your browser.

Comment: Perfect for Laravel 4.0.x where the `log` driver doesn't exist

Comment: This is the quickest solution to my problem, I simply needed to view the email body during a one-off debugging session. Don't forget to `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;`

Answer (score 1):

I created a package to also include subject and body for laravel 4.2.

The package can be found here: https://packagist.org/packages/peercode/mail

Just enable the package as descripted here: https://github.com/peercode-eric/laravel-maillog
and the log will contain the additional information.