# Laravel 5.6 Mail Pretend Feature?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

I'm doing some testing with a Laravel 5.6 (Spark 6.0) and events and notifications set up.

I don't want to send the emails with every test, is there a way it can turned off for testing?

Doing some Googling showed to add a 'prepend' value to the Mail config:

```
'pretend' => env('MAIL_PRETEND', true)
```

However, this doesn't seem to work and I cannot find anything in the Laravel docs for it. Is there still a way to do this in l5.6?

EDIT: By doesn't work, I mean that the mail is still sent via email.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel mail pretend prints nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532353/laravel-mail-pretend-prints-nothing)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy The emails are still sent correctly, which is what I don't want. I wan't them to be pretended to be sent.

Comment: Read the answer to that question closely to have the email print to a `log` file, and not sent.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy The emails are still sent correctly, which is what I don't want. I wan't them to be pretended to be sent.

Comment: Can't you change your driver email in the config to log as stated here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42798745/laravel-mail-to-log ?

Comment: change your MAIL_DRIVER=smtp in .env file to MAIL_DRIVER=log. That's it.

Comment: @parthu_panther That would make sense, have changed the phpunit.xml to reflect this env change too.

Comment: @Lovelock if that worked for you Inform me so I will post it as an answer.

Comment: @parthu_panther Yeah worked, go ahead!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For stopping mail to sent every time while testing you can toggle your MAIL_DRIVER settings.

If its for testing set the settings to `MAIL_DRIVER=log` and for general usage set it to `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp`.